# How to get non Angular Service Worker running in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker

I've been trying to implement a Service Worker into a brand new Angular app. It is not angular's SW, it is just the out of the box api. I'm wanting to purposefully use this one instead of Angular's (just in case that was asked). After reading, it seems like the issue I'm having relates to path issues, but I believe I have the path right. The other issue I've seen is that we can't use `ng serve` and have the SW successfully register, so I've began doing `ng build --prod` and then deploying it using `http-server`, but still I get the following error:

```
Service worker registration failed: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

What steps do I need to get this SW successfully registered?

Also, my file structure is:

```
- main.ts
- index.html
- service-worker.js
```

The `service-worker.js` file is empty and my `main.ts` file is where the registration is contained:

````
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('./service-worker.js')
  .then(registration => console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration)
  , error => console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error));
} else {
  console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));```
````

Answer (score 0):

So I've ended up coming up with a solution, that I would love to get feedback on because of my lack of understanding.

Since I'm running the angular build command, I looked into the `angular.json` file and checked out the build command. I've added the `service-worker.js` to the `assets` array (in the form of `src/service-worker.js`) and also my `manifest.json` file to the array as well because I was having similar issues to the above question, and that fixed everything.

The SW successfully registers after doing the above. I'm guessing because the angular compiler compiles everything into the one output file since it is in the same structure as the `index.html` and specifying those as an asset will make it not be included in the "bundling"?

**NOTE**
Doing this solution also allows me to use `ng-serve` (so no need to build and use `http-server`)